# How to convert one image taken from a camera position to the image from another virtual camera position

Tags: opencv, image-processing, camera, computer-vision, coordinate-transformation

Is it possible to transform one 2D image from one camera (camera1) to the image from another camera (camera2, which is a virtual camera)'s view point under the condition that I know both camera's poses? I looked up some techniques including homography transformation, but it looks not help.

Here is the information I have and I don't have.
- Known: Camera1 pose, camera2 pose (= transformation matrix between two cameras), camera parameters for both cameras
- Unkown: Object pose

If the object 3D pose in the original image is known, the conversion is easy. However, you can't suppose to get the 3D pose (depth) information in my setting.

I believe there is a way because it's already used in the car navigation (www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/12/4/4431/pdf), but I'm curious the general way to realize this transformation. If this is theoretically impossible problem, please let me know too.